# What changes did Erasmus want to make in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, erasmus

Can someone please provide a list of reforms that Erasmus wanted to make to the Catholic Church?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you get a chance, please take the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) Your body should include more than the same sentence 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

I shall not quote it all but Wikipedia has a whole section regarding Erasmus' writing in regard to church reform :

> Erasmus's Sileni Alcibiadis is one of his most direct assessments of the need for Church reform. Johann Froben published it first within a revised edition of the Adagia in 1515, then as a stand-alone work in 1517. This essay has been likened to John Colet's Convocation Sermon, though the styles differ.

> Sileni is the plural (Latin) form of Silenus, a creature often related to the Roman wine god Bacchus and represented in pictorial art as inebriated, merry revellers, variously mounted on donkeys, singing, dancing, playing flutes, etc. Alcibiades was a Greek politician in the 5th century BCE and a general in the Peloponnesian War; he figures here more as a character written into some of Plato's dialogues – a young, debauched playboy whom Socrates tries to convince to seek truth instead of pleasure, wisdom instead of pomp and splendor.

> The term Sileni – especially when juxtaposed with the character of Alcibiades – can therefore be understood as an evocation of the notion that something on the inside is more expressive of a person's character than what one sees on the outside. For instance, something or someone ugly on the outside can be beautiful on the inside, which is one of the main points of Plato's dialogues featuring Alcibiades and the Symposion, in which Alcibiades also appears.

[Erasmus - Wikipedia - Sileni Alcibiadis 1515](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasmus#SileniAlcibiadis)